# Easiest way to access localhost from iPhone

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, network

Imagine the following: I'm a webdeveloper and often have meetings with a client where I want to showcase my current work progress.

I want to showcase this both on my Macbook Pro and iPhone (to showcase responsiveness). I'm searching for a way to easily access the website on my localhost (Macbook) with my iPhone.

Possible solutions which don't work:

**Using Ngrok -** This comes close to what I want. I open the Ngrok URL on my Macbook and then open it on iPhone using the special feature 'Open safari tabs from Macbook'.
However, Ngrok is way to slow and buggy... If it weren't so slow this would be perfect...

**Accessing localhost through network IP -** I know it's possible to access your host machine with your iPhone by browsing to it's IP when the devices are on the same WiFi... But I don't always have the wifi-password of my clients, and it's a hustle to ask (they often don't know/have to search too long)... So not a reliable solution.

**Other solutions? -** What other options do I have? Isn't it possible to access my Macbook with my iPhone when I use my iPhone as personal hotspot (4G)? Or isn't something like this possible with Airdrop?

TL;DR:
I'm searching for the most easy and reliable way to open up my localhost (Macbook) with my iPhone. Without using Wifi. LTE Personal hotspot is allowed. Ngrok to slow.

Comment: Would https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp1540/mac help?

Comment: @nohillside I guess one can share internet from phone too, to get Mac on the same network.

Answer (score 2):

Other than Ngrok, ssh.localhost.run is excellent for that purpose. You need to have the Openssh Client. Use :-

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:port ssh.localhost.run
```

Replace "port" with the port your server is running on. You will receive a link,  just like Ngrok, you can use that link. Other than localhost.run there is also serveo.net, use it the same way as localhost.run, but it is currently down, so localhost.run.

Comment: Perfect and easy solution! Access was blocked to ngrok on my company computer and this worked seamlessly.